# Unparseable date: "2013-05-16 09:35:31.0"

Tags: java, java.util.date

I am getting Parse exception while converting String to date.
Here s my code:

```
String str_date = commonAttrMap.get("updateDate").toString();//2013-05-16 09:35:31.0
DateFormat formatter;
Date date;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss");
date = formatter.parse(str_date);
System.out.println(date);
productDetailForSolr.setUpdateDate(date);
```

Can someone let me know how to parse this.

Comment: Try removing the extra `.0` at the end unless you know why it is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't face any `ParseException` for your `String` (`2013-05-16 09:35:31.0`) as it's completely valid.

```
date = formatter.parse("2013-05-16 09:35:31.0");
   //Assign date to the date Not format
```

It returns the date produced by the given `String` still you will get default format while you print date.To apply your format you have to use `format` method.

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));//date after parsing
```

You wil only get `Unparseable date: "2013-05-10 09:35:31.0"` if you are trying to parse `String` with different date format for example `yyyy/MM/dd`.

Answer (score 1):

If that 0 at the end means milliseconds, try:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S");
```

For the complete reference: have a look at the SimpleDateFormat javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date. The following code is working in both jre6 and jre7.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ParseDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str_date = "2013-05-16 09:35:31.0";
    DateFormat formatter;
    Date date;
    try {
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss");
        date = formatter.parse(str_date);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

You can use the following format also, if you want milliseconds to be parsed,

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S");
```

This is the output I'm getting,

Thu May 16 09:35:31 IST 2013

Answer (score 0):

When reading the javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and looking at your provided timestamp I notice you are also providing milliseconds.

So you get a dateformat string as follows:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormaT("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your date is like `"2013-05-16 09:35:31.0"`, So you need to parse it using the pattern `"yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S"` (here `S` is Milliseconds).

this is what you have to do :

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss.S");
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all Date or Time Component patterns of Date formatter in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in Eclipse.. it is running absolutely fine!!

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class ParseDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String str_date = "2013-05-16 09:35:31.0";
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss");
        date = formatter.parse(str_date);
        System.out.println(date);
    }

}
```

The output is : Thu May 16 09:35:31 ICT 2013

I am using Java jre7